# How to allow multiple signer to sign same document in DocuSign

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, docusignapi

How do I add multiple signer to add sign in same document using c# web API code and start signing ceremony?

I tried to do it by given below code but i's not working -

```
 DocuSign.eSign.Model.Signer signer = new DocuSign.eSign.Model.Signer();
        signer.Email = recipientEmail;
        signer.Name = recipientName;
        signer.RecipientId = "1";
        signer.ClientUserId = "1000";          
        signer.Tabs = new Tabs();
        signer.Tabs.SignHereTabs = new List<SignHere>();

        DocuSign.eSign.Model.Signer nsigner = new DocuSign.eSign.Model.Signer();
        nsigner.Email = "XXX@gmail.com";
        nsigner.Name = "XXX";
        nsigner.RecipientId = "2";
        nsigner.ClientUserId = "2000";
        nsigner.Tabs = new Tabs();
        nsigner.Tabs.SignHereTabs = new List<SignHere>();
        for (int i = 1; i<= numberOfPages; i++)
        {
            SignHere signHere1 = new SignHere();
            signHere1.DocumentId = "1";
            signHere1.PageNumber = i.ToString();
            signHere1.RecipientId = "1";
            signHere1.XPosition = "450";
            signHere1.YPosition = "20";
           
           
            signer.Tabs.SignHereTabs.Add(signHere1);

            SignHere signHere2 = new SignHere();
            signHere2.DocumentId = "1";
            signHere2.PageNumber = i.ToString();
            signHere2.RecipientId = "1";
            signHere2.XPosition = "300";
            signHere2.YPosition = "30";
            

            nsigner.Tabs.SignHereTabs.Add(signHere2);
        }          
       


        envDef.Recipients = new DocuSign.eSign.Model.Recipients();
        envDef.Recipients.Signers = new List<DocuSign.eSign.Model.Signer>();
        envDef.Recipients.Signers.Add(signer);
        envDef.Recipients.Signers.Add(nsigner);
```

To start the embedded signing session, I am using given below code but it's not working for remote server -

```
 System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("chrome.exe",recipientView.Url);
```

Comment: what do you mean by "not working" ?

Comment: it works on your local box? this may be because launching a browser on remote server is not allowed. Is this a console app? winforms? why do you launch the browser instead of navigating? (I assume that means this is not a web app)

Comment: it's a web API that's why I am launching browser. yes it's work on local but not on remote server

Comment: what error do you get on server?

Comment: Not getting any error but signing ceremony also not getting started on the browser using - System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("chrome.exe",recipientView.Url);

Comment: You may need to check the settings of the server. It may be this process is not running elevated, or the server is restricting the ability to open processes. This is not related to DocuSign.

Answer (score 0):

You are missing the code to make the POST API request to create a recipient view for each of the signers. Each such request must contain the information for the specific recipient and gives you back the URL that you can use for embedded signing.
Here is an example using C# and the C# SDK:

```
private static RecipientViewRequest MakeRecipientViewRequest(string signerEmail, string signerName, string returnUrl, string signerClientId, string pingUrl = null)
        {
            // Data for this method
            // signerEmail 
            // signerName
            // dsPingUrl -- class global
            // signerClientId -- class global
            // dsReturnUrl -- class global


            RecipientViewRequest viewRequest = new RecipientViewRequest();
            // Set the url where you want the recipient to go once they are done signing
            // should typically be a callback route somewhere in your app.
            // The query parameter is included as an example of how
            // to save/recover state information during the redirect to
            // the DocuSign signing ceremony. It's usually better to use
            // the session mechanism of your web framework. Query parameters
            // can be changed/spoofed very easily.
            viewRequest.ReturnUrl = returnUrl + "?state=123";

            // How has your app authenticated the user? In addition to your app's
            // authentication, you can include authenticate steps from DocuSign.
            // Eg, SMS authentication
            viewRequest.AuthenticationMethod = "none";

            // Recipient information must match embedded recipient info
            // we used to create the envelope.
            viewRequest.Email = signerEmail;
            viewRequest.UserName = signerName;
            viewRequest.ClientUserId = signerClientId;

            // DocuSign recommends that you redirect to DocuSign for the
            // Signing Ceremony. There are multiple ways to save state.
            // To maintain your application's session, use the pingUrl
            // parameter. It causes the DocuSign Signing Ceremony web page
            // (not the DocuSign server) to send pings via AJAX to your
            // app,
            // NOTE: The pings will only be sent if the pingUrl is an https address
            if (pingUrl != null)
            {
                viewRequest.PingFrequency = "600"; // seconds
                viewRequest.PingUrl = pingUrl; // optional setting
            }

            return viewRequest;
        }
```